# UTF-8 support in Visual Studio 2017 std::experimental::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, visual-studio-2017, c++-experimental

I was happy to see the addition of support for `std::experimental::filesystem` in Visual Studio 2017, but just now ran into issues with Unicode. I kinda blindly assumed that I could use UTF-8 strings everywhere, but failed - when constructing a `std::experimental::filesystem::path` from a `char*` to a UTF-8 encoded string no conversion happens (even though the headers use `_To_wide` and `_To_byte` functions internally. I wrote a simple test example:

```
#include <string>
#include <experimental\filesystem>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

static inline std::string FromUtf16(const wchar_t* pUtf16String)
{
    int nUtf16StringLength = static_cast<int>(wcslen(pUtf16String));
    int nUtf8StringLength = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pUtf16String, nUtf16StringLength, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string sUtf8String(nUtf8StringLength, '\0');
    nUtf8StringLength = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pUtf16String, nUtf16StringLength, const_cast<char *>(sUtf8String.c_str()), nUtf8StringLength, NULL, NULL);
    return sUtf8String;
}

static inline std::string FromUtf16(const std::wstring& sUtf16String)
{
    return FromUtf16(sUtf16String.c_str());
}

static inline std::wstring ToUtf16(const char* pUtf8String)
{
    int nUtf8StringLength = static_cast<int>(strlen(pUtf8String));
    int nUtf16StringLength = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pUtf8String, nUtf8StringLength, NULL, NULL);
    std::wstring sUtf16String(nUtf16StringLength, '\0');
    nUtf16StringLength = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pUtf8String, nUtf8StringLength, const_cast<wchar_t*>(sUtf16String.c_str()), nUtf16StringLength);
    return sUtf16String;
}

static inline std::wstring ToUtf16(const std::string& sUtf8String)
{
    return ToUtf16(sUtf8String.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string sTest(u8"Kaķis");
    std::wstring sWideTest(ToUtf16(sTest));
    wchar_t pWideTest[1024] = {};
    char pByteTest[1024];
    std::experimental::filesystem::path Path1(sTest), Path2(sWideTest);
    std::experimental::filesystem::v1::_To_wide(sTest.c_str(), pWideTest);
    bool bWideEqual = sWideTest == pWideTest;
    std::experimental::filesystem::v1::_To_byte(pWideTest, pByteTest);
    bool bUtf8Equal = sTest == pByteTest;
    bool bPathsEqual = Path1 == Path2;
    printf("wide equal: %d, utf-8 equal: %d, paths equal: %d\n", bWideEqual, bUtf8Equal, bPathsEqual);
}
```

But as I stated earlier, I just blindly assumed that UTF-8 would work. Looking at [std::experimental::filesystem::path on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/path) under the constructor secion it actually states that:

> - If the source character type is char, the encoding of the source is
>     assumed to be the native narrow encoding (so no conversion takes
>     place on POSIX systems)
> - If the source character type is char16_t,
>     conversion from UTF-16 to native filesystem encoding is used.
> - If the source character type is char32_t, conversion from UTF-32 to native
>     filesystem encoding is used.
> - If the source character type is wchar_t,
>     the input is assumed to be the native wide encoding (so no conversion
>     takes places on Windows)

I am not sure how to interpret the first line. First, it states something only about POSIX systems (even though I do not understand what is the native narrow encoding, does that mean UTF-8 will not work on POSIX as well?). Second, it does not state anything about Windows, and MSDN is silent on this as well. So, how to property handle initializaiton of `std::experimental::filesystem::path` from Unicode characters in a cross-platform safe manner?

Comment: In Visual Studio `path(u8"utf8")` is treated as ANSI. This is consistent with the documentation because Windows supports ANSI (which you don't want in a new application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "narrow" (8-bit) encoding of `filesystem::path` depends on the environment and host OS.  It might be UTF-8 on many POSIX systems, but it also may not.  If you want to use UTF-8, you should use it explicitly, via [`std::filesystem::path::u8string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) and [`std::filesystem::u8path()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/u8path)